# Does JEST support gzip for bulk operation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

Does JEST Java client lib for elasticsearch support gzip (compression) for huge bulk operations? I'm uploading thousands of documents in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to do two things:

1. set [`http.compression: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restart ES
2. call `setRequestCompressionEnabled(true)` on your Jest client.